# How to use a private enum in a private method using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I got an internal method where one of the input parameter is an internal Enum. How do I get a enum value and pass it to the method?

Example:

```
internal enum MyEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}


internal int InternalTest(string test, MyEnum enumTest)
{
    return test.Length;
}
```

And then obtained by something like this:

```
MethodInfo addInternal = typeof(Class1).GetMethod("InternalTest", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(?????) }, null);
```

Thanks!

Ivar

Comment: There must be a reason why this method and enum are `internal`...

Comment: This solution will not work. GetMethod() returns only *public* methods.

Comment: Alexandre: Wrong. GetMethod() and BindingFlags.NonPublic will return "non public" methods. Same for all reflection methods, if you use BindingFlags.NonPublic, you also can access private members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `typeof(Class1).GetNestedTypes()`. It should return a list all types that nested into Class1 - like MyEnum is. So look through the list of nested types, find the MyEnum type and pass it to GetMethod.

GetNestedTypes documentation on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getnestedtypes(v=vs.100).aspx

There is also a `GetNestedType()` method that accepts a type name and some BindingFlags which allows you to search for specific nested type by name.

To get a value of the enum using reflection, use this:

```
object enumValue = myEnumType.GetField("ValueName", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Comment: Re GetField - that is only useful if you know the value in terms of a field. Not so useful for [Flags] enums, or when the value depends on other things at runtime, and a numeric representation is often more convenient prior to the final step.

Comment: Marc, but it's the only way to get typed enum values using reflection. and to make sure that you do not create enum values to do not exist. The given exampel code does not show Flags enum, so GetField is fine.

Comment: Wrong. The GetNestedType() method returns *public* nested types, and the question is about private/internal types.

Comment: @Alexandre: You're wrong. There is also a GetNestedTypes() overload that accepts a type name and BindingFlags - you can use this to retrieve internal/private types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/493t6h7t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The enum was not in a class so I had to use Assembly.GetTypes(). Thank you for leading me in the right direction

Comment: @Carsten if you know the name you probably know the underlying value you want too

Answer (score 3):

If it is in a different assembly, then getting the type would have to be by name, for example;

```
Type type = assembly.GetType("SomeNamespace.SomeType+SomeNestedType");
```

Which might be (from the example):

```
Type type = typeof(Class1).Assembly.GetType("Class1+MyEnum");
```

A more interesting question is: how to get a *value* (boxed to the correct type) for the enum - you need something like:

```
object val = Enum.ToObject(type, 123);
```

Comment: And that was my next question. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Get it by calling the `GetNestedTypes()` method:

```
Type type = typeof(Program).GetNestedTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsEnum);
```

This will return the (arbitrary) enum in the type. If you want to find it by name or something, use a different lambda.

Comment: Except GetNestedTypes() only returns *public* nested types, and the question is about private/internal nested type.

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon: GetNestedTypes() can take a BindingFlags enum which means you can ask for private types on platforms that support it.